# Change border color of TextField while focused

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm restyling my cross-platform app made with NativeScript + Angular and I want to change the border color of a textfield when I'm putting data on it.

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```css
TextField {
  margin-bottom: 10;
  border-radius: 4;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-width: 0.5;
  border-color: #C4C4C4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

TextField:focus{
  border-color: red;
}
```

This is a part of login.component.html:

```
        <label text="Email"></label>
        <TextField 
            hint="mario.rossi@gmail.com" 
            keyboardType="email" 
            autocorrect="false"
            autocapitalizationType="none" 
            [(ngModel)]="user.email" 
            class="input"></TextField>
        <label text="Password"></label>
        <TextField
            hint="Password"
            secure="true"
            [(ngModel)]="user.password"
            class="input"></TextField>
```

How can I do?
Here is the [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jGx0E4)

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`. Please provide a [mcve] of your issue when poisting a question, and read [ask] before posting it.

Comment: Now is it ok? Or do you need more infos?

Comment: why its not working, tell me one reason ?

Comment: Because when I write in it, the border color doesn't change. It remains with the default color

Comment: Use input instead of TextField. input[type="text"]:focus{
  border-color: red;
}

Comment: @gsarme definitely more information. Just reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com. Also, I don't why it's related to Angular, as it is only CSS. Until proven otherwise, I am removing the Angular tag (nad other irrelevant ones) as to not pollute them.

Comment: @Maryannah it's not only CSS because the code above in other context it works (see adel answer). In this case, with Nativescript + Angular, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 can you make a Playgroud, please?

Comment: **until proven otherwise**, this is css code. You don't have an ounce of js code in your question. So **again**, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your issue. If there is js, I will add back the tags myself.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NativeScript doesn't support any pseudo-selector while text field is focused. But you could simply listen to focus and blur events, add / remove a class for changing border color.

Since you are using Angular, a simple directive could solve this problem once in for all TextFields in your app.

**HTML**

```
<ScrollView class="page">
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <TextField appHighlightBorder class="m-10 input input-border"
            hint="First Name"></TextField>
        <TextField appHighlightBorder class="m-b-10 m-x-10 input input-border"
            hint="Last Name"></TextField>
        <TextField appHighlightBorder class="m-b-10 m-x-10 input input-border"
            hint="Email"></TextField>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**CSS**

```
.form .input-border.focus {
    border-color: red;
}
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import { TextField } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHighlightBorder]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnDestroy {

    private removeFocusEvent: () => void;
    private removeBlurEvent: () => void;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.removeFocusEvent = this.renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, TextField.focusEvent, () => {
            renderer.addClass(elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus');
        });
        this.removeBlurEvent = this.renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, TextField.blurEvent, () => {
            renderer.removeClass(elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus');
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.removeFocusEvent();
        this.removeBlurEvent();
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=WgZ2eX)

Comment: Thank you! If I want this function in all my component can I put the Directive file on the app folder?

Comment: Are you familiar with Angular? If you are using lazy loaded modules, put the directive on shared module. If your modules are early loaded then adding it to app module might work.

Comment: To add to the above, I followed a tutorial [here](https://alligator.io/angular/providers-shared-modules/) to properly set up a shared module and have the directive available.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use the focus event from css and change the border color.
if this is your TextField:
`<TextField class="input"></TextField>`
the css rule will be:

```
.input:focus{
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not there by default. However, you could implement it by yourself with `focus` and `blur` events.

For example:

*`<some-page>.xml`*

```xml
...
<TextField class="input-field"
    text="{{ email }}"
    keyboardType="email"
    autocapitalizationType="none"
    autocorrect="false"
    focus="onTextFieldFocus"
    blur="onTextFieldBlur" />
...
```

*`<some-page>.ts`*

```ts
...
const focusedPseudoClass = "focused";

export function onTextFieldFocus(args: EventData) {
    const textField = <TextField>args.object;
    textField.addPseudoClass(focusedPseudoClass);
}

export function onTextFieldBlur(args: EventData) {
    const textField = <TextField>args.object;
    textField.deletePseudoClass(focusedPseudoClass);
}
...
```

*`<some-page>.css`*

```css
...
.input-field {
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-bottom-width: 1;
}
.input-field:focused {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
...
```

Comment: I'm using Angular so my page component isn't .xml, is .html. I try this code but id doesn't work for me.

Comment: Create a simple playground with your attempt to get more exact help. And yes in your original post you did not nation that you are using Angular ☹️.

Comment: I added the tag Angular but someone still remove that tag. As soon as I have time I'll create a Playground.

Comment: This is my [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jGx0E4), if you have any idea of why it doesn't work please tell me, I'm going crazy!

Answer (score -1):

```css
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10;
  border-radius: 4;
  background: #FFFFFF;
 outline:0;
  border-width: 0.5;
  border-color: #C4C4C4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea:focus{
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

just removed outline from textarea!

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your css file. Hope it works.

```
 TextField:focus {
       outline: none !important;
       border-color: red;
     }
```

Comment: try using textarea

Comment: NativeScript does snot support  any pseudo-selecto